# How can I prevent floats and doubles from getting truncated in Java and C?

Tags: java, c, floating-point

When I give Java and C large floats and doubles (in the billion range), they convert them to scientific notation, losing precision in the process. How can I stop this behavior?

Comment: Have you tried passing them as Strings?  They will remain immutable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For Java, check out [BigDecimal](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Answer (score 8):

The conversion to scientific notation is purely an effect of how it's displayed.  Changing the display is a matter of how you output it (format specifiers)

floats generally have about 6 digits of precision, which would make them inappropriate to hold a number in the billions. Doubles have about 15 digits of precision, so it should be able to hold numbers well past trillions with full accuracy.

To display a double in C:

```
printf("%10f", dbl);
```